# the method that handles the button action never inserted when the button is dragged

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am trying to drag a button in the .m file as shown in the image below, but after releasing the mouse button the method that handles the button when clicked was never implemented.

please let me why that method gets never inserted in the .m file??

**image**:

[image]

Comment: Sometimes Xcode starts misbehaving. Did you try restarting it?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight yes I did..and the issue persists

Comment: didn't you forget to set the class name in storyboard for your viewcontroller ? :/

Comment: @MohyG would you please tell me how to do it??

Comment: @user2121 select your view controller in storyBoard and in the right pane select identity inspector tab, under `Custom Class` section write down your class name instead of `UIViewController` , in your case its `viewController` and done.
if you do this , assistant editor on automatic mode will bring up the code related to the selected viewController

Answer (score 0):

Choose your ViewController in IB by clicking on the yellow circle with a square inside. Select the third tab on Xcode's right pane. Choose ViewController as your class for this IB item from the combobox. After that, the binding should work.

Answer (score 0):

The storyboard viewcontroller must be a subclassed from the class you are trying to drag into (by default its UIviewController) If it's not then it won't work...

From your storyboard click on viewController and then in the inspector panel on your right change it to the right class and you should be all good.